# How to assign importance levels to ints?

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I'm having to make a program that allows a gerbil to go mining for four metals and the four metals have different levels of value. The gerbil can only carry 10 ounces at a time. The gerbil will prioritize carrying metals of higher value. I am just beginning classes, methods, and constructors, so the code I'm doing can't have anything too advanced. Any help? Here is what I have so far.

```
public class Gerbil {
private int totalRhodium;
private int totalPlatinum;
private int totalGold;
private int totalIron;
private int totals;
private int limit=10;

public Gerbil() {

}

public int printTotals() {
    totals=totalRhodium+totalPlatinum+totalGold+totalIron;
    return totals;
}

public void goMining(int rhodium, int platinum, int gold, int iron) {

    System.out.println("Rhodium: "+rhodium);
    System.out.println("Platinum: "+platinum);
    System.out.println("Gold: "+gold);
    System.out.println("Iron: "+iron);
}
```

}

Comment: You will need to use loops to implement this stuff

Comment: you can use a hashmap with the key being the priority and the value being the metal itself

Comment: @Akshay oh, I thought I would need to...i guess I would do it in the goMining method. I'm just not sure where how to figure out exactly the program will know if one metal is important over another.

Comment: try with if..else else if loops...play arround a bit or else you will not learn

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
...
int totals = 0;
int totalsRhodium = 0;
int totalsPlatinum = 0;
int totalsGold = 0;
int totalsIron = 0;
int limit = 10;

public void goMining(int rhodium, int platinum, int gold, int iron) {

    if(rhodium >= limit) {
        this.totalsRhodium = limit;
        return;
    } else {
        this.totalsRhodium = rhodium;
        limit = limit - rhodium;
    }

    if(platinum >= limit) {
        this.totalsPlatinum = limit;
        return;
    } else {
        this.totalsPlatinum = platinum;
        limit = limit - platinum;
    }

    //go on with the other metals
}
```